# phoenix module ExAws.S3.Client is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, phoenix-framework

I use the library https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws, and I faced such problem:

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/s3.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/models/s3.ex:2: module ExAws.S3.Client is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/models/s3.ex:2: Minion.S3 (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:116: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

in my mix.exs:

```
  def application do
    [mod: {Minion, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, ... :ex_aws, :httpoison, :poison]]
  end
...
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
...
     {:ex_aws, "~> 1.0.0-beta0"},
     {:poison, "~> 2.0"},
     {:httpoison, "~> 0.8"}]
  end
```

my config.exs:

```
config :minion, :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: "...",
  secret_access_key: "...",
  region: "us-east-1",
  s3: [
    scheme: "http://",
    host: "...",
    region: "us-east-1"
  ]
```

my s3.ex:

```
defmodule Minion.S3 do
  use ExAws.S3.Client, otp_app: :minion
end
```

I will be grateful for any help to fix this problem

Comment: It said `ExAws.S3.Client` is not loaded.Where is your `ExAws.S3.Client` module?

Comment: @TheAnhLeI think it is sufficient in the deps and `applications: [:phoenix, ... :ex_aws, :httpoison, :poison]`. even as the need to load the module?

Comment: I checked the newest release and there is no module name `ExAws.S3.Client`.You probably follow an old guide version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:ex_aws`in version >= 1.0.0 does not use the old (pre 1.0.0) style where you needed to do as in your module `Minion.S3`. That's why `ExAws.S3.Client` does not exists. Instead, try:

1. Remove your file s3.ex
2. In config.exs, change from `config :minion, :ex_aws,` to `config :ex_aws,`
3. Update your requests to the new style: `S3.list_buckets |> ExAws.request #=> {:ok, response}` instead of old style `Minion.S3.list_buckets`